# How to send the content of a dictionary properly over sockets in python3x?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, dictionary

Using sockets in `python3.x` I want to send the content of a dictionary over a socket, which for some reasons is NOT answered by the link just above this line...

client.py:

```
a = {'test':1, 'dict':{1:2, 3:4}, 'list': [42, 16]}
bytes = foo(a)
sock.sendall(bytes)
```

server.py:

```
bytes = sock.recv()
a = bar(bytes)
print(a)
```

How to convert any dictionary to a sequence of bytes (to be able to be sent through a socket) and how to be converted back? I prefer a clean and simple way to do this.

What I have tried so far:

```
sock.sendall(json.dumps(data))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

sock.sendall(bytes(data, 'UTF-8'))
TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument

data = sock.recv(100)
a= data.decode('UTF-8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: What about serializing it to JSON? https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html Would it be sufficient for your needs or do you need to transfer more than just lists, dicts, strings, True/False/None and ints/floats?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190362/sending-a-dictionary-using-sockets-in-python

Comment: This does not seem to work. I tried `sock.sendall(json.dumps(data))` with data being a `dict` and got an error `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

Comment: For that `TypeError`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Comment: @dano: Well, because of that error I posted my question in the first place. The solution in the link you posted also does not work, because of an error  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is primarily summarizing the comments, but you need to convert the dict to a json `str` object, convert that `str` object to a `bytes` object by encoding it, and then send that over the socket. On the server-side, you need to decode the `bytes` object sent over the socket back to a `str`, and then use `json.loads` to turn it back into a `dict`.

Client:

```
b = json.dumps(a).encode('utf-8')
s.sendall(b)
```

Server:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 1234))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
b = b''
while 1:
    tmp = conn.recv(1024)
    b += tmp
d = json.loads(b.decode('utf-8'))
print(d)
```

Comment: Well, I cannot test your suggestion as I now (after simplifying my scipt) get an error `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`.

Comment: @Alex, that's a separate problem. I'll expand my server-side example code which will probably reveal your error. My guess is you're using the original `socket` object to call `recv` instead of the one returned by `sock.accept`.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote my whole proof-of-concept example AGAIN, and your suggestion works! But what do I do if the object to receive is larger than 1024 bytes? I can read the byte bits in a while loop which gets added to an empty string? I might need create an empty byte variable or something. Or just increase the number of bytes to  receive in `recv` to something really big?

Comment: @Alex, You can make the buffer larger if you know there's going to be some limit on the size of the dict you send. Otherwise you do the recv in a while loop, like you said. the Python documentation for `socket` shows that in action: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example

Comment: The link you posted does no show an example of reading data from `recv` and 'adding' them together. If the data rom `recv` ist just text (like in python 2.x) this is very easy, as you initialize an empty string. But for python 3.x you need to initialize an empty byte object or something...

Comment: @Alex, right. Luckily, making an empty `byte` is easy. See my edit.