# Python - dictionary object over socket

Tags: python-3.x

How to send dictionary datatype object over a socket? I know from Python 3, we have to use encode() and decode() while sending and receving a string through a socket, like socket.send(data.encode()) and `socket.recv(data.decode())`. How are we supposed the same thing for dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
serialized_dictionary = json.dumps(your_dictionary) 
your_dictionary=json.loads(serialized_dictionary)
```

Don't forget to import json module:

```
import json
```

Hope this helps! =)

[More on json module here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Found a similar question (check this too):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190362/sending-a-dictionary-using-sockets-in-python